# How to test timestamps using capybara?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sinatra, capybara

I have a program in which a user can post a 'peep', along with it being timestamped. How can I test this using capybara? The problem is everytime a new timestramp is created, the time differs. Would I have to create some sort of stub/mock in capybara? Help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

```
class Peep

  include DataMapper::Resource

  property :id, Serial
  property :title, String
  property :text, String
  property :created_at, DateTime

end

DataMapper.setup(:default, "postgres://localhost/chitter_#{ENV['RACK_ENV']}")
DataMapper.finalize
DataMapper.auto_upgrade!
```

App.rb:

```
require 'data_mapper'
require 'sinatra/base'
require 'sinatra/flash'
require_relative './models/peep.rb'
require_relative './models/user.rb'
ENV["RACK_ENV"] ||= "development"

class Chitter < Sinatra::Base

  enable :sessions
  register Sinatra::Flash
  set :session_secret, 'super secret'

  get '/' do
    'You arrived at the homepage'
  end

  get '/peeps' do
    @peeps = Peep.all
    erb(:index)
  end

  get '/peeps/new' do
    erb(:new)
  end

  get '/users/new' do
    @user = User.new
    erb(:'users/new')
  end

  post '/users' do
  @user = User.create(email: params[:email],
                    password: params[:password],
                    password_confirmation: params[:password_confirmation])
    if @user.save
      session[:user_id] = @user.id
      redirect to('/peeps')
    else
      flash.now[:errors] = @user.errors.full_messages
      erb(:'users/new')
    end

  end

  post '/peeps' do
    peep = Peep.new(title: params[:title], text: params[:text])
    peep.save
    redirect to('/peeps')
  end

  helpers do
    def current_user
      @current_user ||= User.get(session[:user_id])
    end
  end

  run! if app_file == $PROGRAM_NAME
end
```

Views:

```
<h1> Peeps </h1>

<ul id='peeps'>
  <% @peeps.reverse.each do |peep| %>
   <li id="peeps">
    Title: <%= peep.title %>
    Text:  <%= peep.text %>
    created_at: <%= peep.created_at %>
  </li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

Comment: What exactly you want to test? How you have tried? What problem you are fetching?

Answer (score 2):

If doing this in a capybara driven feature test, the easiest solution is to use one of the time travelling/freezing solutions such as `timecop` - https://github.com/travisjeffery/timecop - so that your test can be wrapped in a method that freezes the time.

```
Timecop.freeze(specific_datetime) do
  # fill out form
  ...
  # submit form
  ...
  expect(page).to have_content("created_at: #{specific_datetime.tos}") # format the specific_datetime as expected
end
```

Note: If the date was actually being set in the browser by JS you'd need to also use something like `sinon.js` to freeze the browser time too.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using RSpec you could probably do something like:

```
RSpec.describe Peep do
  let(:peep) { Peep.create(title: "My title", text: "Some text") }

  describe "#created_at" do        
    it { expect(peep).to respond_to(:created_at) }
    it { expect(peep.created_at).to be_kind_of(DateTime) }
  end
end
```

I would recommend not thoroughly testing that the functionality provided by DataMapper works as intended, as doing so would be very involved. It's a third party library that is also tested. Testing that you have added the line `property :created_at, DateTime` correctly, however, could be achieved with the above specs.